# Javascript find in List

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<datalist id="MyList">
            <option title="SomeId">SomeName</option>
            <option title="SomeId">SomeName</option>
            <option title="SomeId">SomeName</option>
            <option title="SomeId">SomeName</option>
</datalist>
```

Connected to this input:

```
<input id="MyPicker" type="text" list="MyList" onclick="this.value = ''">
```

Then I have this code:

```
document.querySelector('input[list="MyList"]').addEventListener('input', onInput);
function onInput(e) {
        var input = e.target,
            val = input.value;
        list = input.getAttribute('list'),
            options = document.getElementById(list).childNodes;

        var myItem;
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var trimmed_option = options[i].innerText;
            try {
                trimmed_option = trimmed_option.trim();
            } catch (err) { }
            if (trimmed_option == val.trim()) {
                myItem = options[i];
                alert("I got it");
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

What I am doing is: Find current item in the list. I am however only able to find item only in some occasions.

What I want to do: I want to be able to find item everytime.

My idea: I could find it based on `id` of `<option>` but I was unable to do that.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: What exactly you want? do you want to get the value from input box after option selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really uncertain about what you want. The `<datalist>` mechanism you are using here already works without any JavaScript, see below (I commented out the attachment of the event-listener). What exactly do you want to achieve with your script?

```js
// document.querySelector('input[list="MyList"]').addEventListener('input', onInput);
function onInput(e) {
    var input = e.target,
        val = input.value;
    list = input.getAttribute('list'),
        options = document.getElementById(list).childNodes;

    var myItem;
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var trimmed_option = options[i].innerText;
        try {
            trimmed_option = trimmed_option.trim();
        } catch (err) { }
        if (trimmed_option == val.trim()) {
            myItem = options[i];
            alert("I got it");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<datalist id="MyList">
        <option title="hp">Harry Potter</option>
        <option title="hg">Hermione Granger</option>
        <option title="rw">Ron Weasley</option>
        <option title="gw">Ginny Weasley</option>
</datalist>
<input id="MyPicker" type="text" list="MyList" onclick="this.value = ''">
```